# Class construction based on interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, instantiation

Imagine that we have classes as such:

```
public abstract class WebPage
{ 
    public WebPage() 
    { ... } 
}

public class LoginOrSignUpWebPage : WebPage, ILogin, ISignUp
{
    private Info _loginInfo;
    private Info _signUpInfo;
    public readonly Info LoginInfo { get { return _meats; } }
    public readonly Info SignUpInfo { get { return _legs; } }

    public class LoginOrSignUpWebPage(Info loginInfo, Info signUpInfo) : base()
    { ... }
}
```

We can see that `WebPage`s would want to have different ways of being instantiated based on different interfaces they implement.

Whilst it'd feel okay implementing individual constructions for each class, I would prefer to use inheritance to base the object construction upon. The reason for this is because another object may implement the same interfaces and would have the same way of being instantiated.
I have thought about using some sort of (abstract?) Factory method, but I'm not sure how this would work.

**Question:**

Right to the point, what do you think would be the best way to base construction of an object based upon what interfaces it inherits? This would include (potentially) different parameters, and at minimum different data passed depending on the implemented interface.

Comment: So you want to abstract away construction of animals? Like a factory? Can you give an example how such a factory would be used?

Comment: Well pointed out, perhaps Animals weren't the best example! I'll change that.

Comment: Edited above, hopefully that's more understandable of an example.

Comment: Two things: 1) I agree with a factory but not sure it is really needed; 2) you should have a `LoginWebPage` and a `SignUpWebPage`. You are really selling the design short if you try to have an "either/or" object. What if tomorrow you decide to have other 'sign-up types': `RequestInfoWebPage`, `GetEmailsWebPage`, etc.

Comment: I can understand that, but please let's not read too far into the example. The question is more about the **way** that objects are instantiated with a constructor or factory method based upon implemented interfaces. This could apply generally to a number of situations past the example. Perhaps how I asked the question was a bit lazy - please see the edit for the last paragraph about the quesiton.

Comment: Do you want automatic dependency injection based on the ctor parameters or interfaces? That would mean a reflection based solution. Can you use a DI container for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can see that `WebPage`s would want to have different ways of being instantiated based on different interfaces they implement.

No, they wouldn’t. Interfaces define how types should look like to the outside. They provide no implementation detail and also no information about the constructor or the construction process. If you have an object of the type of an interface, all you know is that you can access the properties and methods that were defined in the interface.

The way you declare your `WebPage` type, it is *fixed* to implement both `ILogin` and `ISignUp`. As such it is *absolutely required* to implement whatever these two interfaces specify. And every object of type `WebPage` will always provide what both interfaces require.

It is not necessary to make the construction of an object based on the interfaces it is implementing, simply because the interfaces you are implementing is known at compile time and can’t be changed later. So for the type implementing an interface, you just specify directly how that is constructed.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that does make sense, sorry about that. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: To add to this, signup and login are different use cases, and should probably be separate pages.